# Can't decode Json array values?

Tags: java, android

How to get these JSON values in android?

```
{
    "one": [
        {
            "ID": "100",
            "Name": "Hundres"
        }
    ],
    "two": [
        {
            "ID": "200",
            "Name": "two hundred"
        }
    ],
    "success": 1
}
```

I tried the following but it shows that the length is 0. I can't get the array values.

```
JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url_new);
try {
    getcast = json.getJSONArray("one");
    int length = getcast.length();
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: But cant get the array ,it display the values as zero

Comment: are you sure that the message from the Json is exactly the one you posted?? can you check it first.

Comment: Are you sure the json is getting to there properly? Try to log the `json.toString()` and make sure it is right.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following line in your code

```
String str = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url).tostring();
```

Following is the Code Snippet which worked for me

```
String str = "{"
                + "\"one\": ["
                +        "{"
                +            "\"ID\": \"100\","
                +            "\"Name\": \"Hundres\""
                +        "}"
                +    "],"
                +    "\"two\": ["
                +       " {"
                +           " \"ID\": \"200\","
                +           " \"Name\": \"two hundred\""
                +       " }"
                +    "],"
                +    "\"success\": 1"
                + "}"; 

        try {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(str);
        JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("one");
        int n = arr.length();

        String id;
        String name;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
          JSONObject person = arr.getJSONObject(i);
          id =  person.getString("ID");
          name = person.getString("Name");
        }

        arr = obj.getJSONArray("two");
        n = arr.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
          JSONObject person = arr.getJSONObject(i);
          id =  person.getString("ID");
          name = person.getString("Name");
        }

        int success = obj.getInt("success");
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
```

Answer (score -2):

I guess the failure lies in the first line. What kind of value is url_new?
If you could get the Json from above in form of a String I'd recommend constructing the JSONObject json from the constructor JSONObject(String source) like here:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(json_string);
```

That's how I use to extract the JSON from API-calls.

Reference: http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html
You can see all constructors here.

Comment: could u give some reference

Comment: updated reference, so if you have the json as a string you can construct your JSONObject as I explained above.

Comment: @Mofodev He is using a library to retrieve it. The library constructs and returns a `JSONObject`.

Comment: @miro: I cant get the length